# Mac Mini won't start

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

I got a 2007 Mac Mini off eBay a year ago. Now it won't start. It will show the Apple logo and then when it gets to the blue screen where it would normally show the desktop, the DVI cuts out.

I have taken it apart before, I upgraded the RAM. The back ribbon cable is unplugged which may be the sound. It does start occasionally and when it does I have no sound. The front black plug is also unplugged, which seems to be fan control as it's loud when it's unplugged. (The front black plug wire is broken.)

Any ideas on what to do?

Note: it gets to the blue screen and then the dvi connection drops.

Comment: Are you saying the fans are not running?

Comment: This seems like a software issue, if it were video connection issue it should fail immediately. Have you tried starting it in safe mode by holding down the shift key while booting and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @ranman They may or may not. It's louder when it's unplugged, so it may just be the fan speed control, but not sure as it may not look like it was running when I pull the core unit out. But it also hasn't overheated, so who knows.

Comment: @MrDaniel I'll try that. Is it possible that the Mac uses HDCP when it's running and maybe the HDCP connection is bad, so it shows the boot up but then drops?

Comment: It was on a blank screen but didn't drop signal, then when I tried again later it still dropped signal. The video also flashes sometimes during boot and there's also never a chime even when it does boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be the DVI-cable. For some reason, the DVI-cable works better with my PC than the Mac. I plugged it in via VGA and it works.